# BlackBerry example project will not compile for VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, blackberry-10

Honestly I am not 100% sure what I am looking at with this output. The best I can tell is that there is an issue with the VCInstallDir macro, and potentially the qcc compiler path is not set to ("C:\bbndk_vs\host_10_3_0_2702\win32\x86\usr\bin") I do not know how to verify this.

For now I would be happy to just get a second opinion on this. If anybody can tell me exactly what I need to fix that is great too, and I would really appreciate that!

If I compile with 10.2 sdk selected with the BB10 plugin for VS2013 I get this output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: DiceRoller, Configuration: Debug BlackBerry ------
1>Build started 14/07/2014 1:25:05 PM.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(361,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find VCInstallDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Device-Debug\DiceRoller.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
1>Link:
1>  qcc -o main.o C:/src/2014/BB10/DiceRoller/src/main.c -V"4.6.3,gcc_ntoarmv7le" -c -Wp,-MMD,main.d -Wp,-MT,main.o -g -w3 -lang-c -fexceptions -fstack-protector-all -I"C:\VS2013\VC\include" -I"C:\VS2013\VC\atlmfc\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt" -I"C:\src\Libraries" -I"C:\bbndk\target_10_2_0_1155\qnx6\usr\include" -DQCC -D__QCC__ -D__QNX__ -UWIN32 -U_WINDOWS 
1>  'qcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
1>  operable program or batch file.
1>  x86\usr\bin\make: *** [main.o] Error 1
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.44
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I compile with either of the 10.3 sdk options selected with the BB10 plugin for VS2013 I get output that looks like this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: DiceRoller, Configuration: Debug BlackBerry ------
1>Build started 14/07/2014 1:54:48 PM.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(361,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find VCInstallDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Device-Debug\DiceRoller.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
1>Link:
1>  qcc -o main.o C:/src/2014/BB10/DiceRoller/src/main.c -V"4.6.3,gcc_ntoarmv7le" -c -Wp,-MMD,main.d -Wp,-MT,main.o -g -w3 -lang-c -fexceptions -fstack-protector-all -I"C:\VS2013\VC\include" -I"C:\VS2013\VC\atlmfc\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt" -I"C:\src\Libraries" -I"C:\bbndk\target_10_2_0_1155\qnx6\usr\include" -DQCC -D__QCC__ -D__QNX__ -UWIN32 -U_WINDOWS 
1>  cc1: fatal error: "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um": Invalid argument
1>  compilation terminated.
1>  cc: C:/bbndk_vs/host_10_3_0_2702/win32/x86/usr/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0eabi/4.6.3/cc1 caught signal 1
1>  makefile:33: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
1>  x86\usr\bin\make: *** [main.o] Error 1
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.76
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to build a [QNX-Project](http://www.qnx.com/download/group.html?programid=26071) with Visual Studio. Are you sure this is intended to work properly at all?

Comment: Yes I am sure. "BlackBerry Native Plug-in for Visual Studio"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why 10.2 doesn't have a compiler installed with it. I will likely search on the blackberry developer forms to resolve that.

The 10.3 error however.. this is occurring, I believe, because the qcc compiler does not accept spaces in directory paths. All the BlackBerry related sdk paths lack spaces, that error is pointing at a windows sdk directory however.

This question's issue can/was fixed by removing non blackberry related directories from the property pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have qcc on your system.  It's not finding it to run it.  Either because it's missing, or isn't in a path that it's looking through.  Not sure if VS uses the system path or it's own.

Comment: Yes it is I found it at C:\bbndk_vs\host_10_3_0_2702\win32\x86\usr\bin